# Using two different measures in a having statement

Tags: mysql

I am including the code I am trying to use.  What I want is to get a count of encounter id's for each doctor.  I want to capture patients who have had at least 2 visits or who have had one preventive visit.  I don't know how to make this work using the having statement.  thanks for any assistance.

```
SELECT  e.doctorID, COUNT(DISTINCT e.encounterID) AS VisitCount

FROM enc e

JOIN users u ON e.patientID = u.uid
Left JOIN diagnosis d ON e.encounterID = d.encounterID
LEFT JOIN items it ON d.itemID = it.itemID
LEFT JOIN itemdetail id ON it.itemID = id.itemID

WHERE e.encType = 1 AND e.status = 'CHK' AND e.deleteFlag = 0 AND 
e.date BETWEEN DATE_ADD((LAST_DAY(DATE_ADD(CURDATE(),INTERVAL -2 MONTH))), INTERVAL 1 DAY) AND LAST_DAY(DATE_ADD(CURDATE(),INTERVAL -1 MONTH)) 
    AND FLOOR(DATEDIFF(NOW(),u.ptdob)/365.25) >= 18 AND e.doctorID = e.resourceID 

        GROUP BY e.doctorID, id.value
        HAVING 
        COUNT(e.patientid)>=2 OR 
        id.value in ('Z00.00', 'Z00.01')
```

Comment: Why are you grouping by `e.doctorID` when your question is about patients?

Comment: Try this in your having clause: `or sum(id.value in ('Z00.00', 'Z00.01')) > 0`. And remove `id.value` from group by clause.

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to include id.value in grp by clause. Try to give valid condition in having clause with id.value

```
select e.doctorID,
COUNT(distinct e.encounterID) as VisitCount from enc e join users u on e.patientID = u.uid 
left join diagnosis d on e.encounterID = d.encounterID left join items it on 
d.itemID = it.itemID left join itemdetail id on 
it.itemID = id.itemID where e.encType = 1 and e.status ='CHK' and e.deleteFlag = 0 and
&nbsp;e.date between DATE_ADD((LAST_DAY(DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL - 2 MONTH))), INTERVAL 1 DAY) 
and LAST_DAY(DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL - 1 MONTH)) 
and 
FLOOR(DATEDIFF(NOW(), u.ptdob) / 365.25) >= 18 
and e.doctorID = e.resourceID group by e.doctorID
having COUNT(e.patientid) >= 2 
or sum(case when id.value in ('Z00.00','Z00.01') then 1
else 0 end)>=1
```